# SetLayeredWindowAttributes not working under certain conditions

Tags: c++, windows, haxe, haxeflixel, flixel

I'm making this app in Haxe which compiles to C++ code. I'm using the `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()` function to set the background of the window to be fully transparent. The problem is that this works completely fine only on certain monitors, but not on others.

If I launch the app on my main monitor, which I believe to be 32-bit (if that matters), the background doesn't change at all, or will flicker and then completely disappear until I focus another window.

However, if I connect another monitor and run the app on that one, the background does become transparent, and the transparency persists even if I move it back to my main monitor. Even with the 2nd monitor connected at the same time. If I launch it on the main one, transparency fails.

I have tried changing the color values between `0xFFffffff`/`0xffffff`, etc, but no combination of these work.

This same problem occurs even on a completely different machine with different hardware than mine. My hardware: Lenovo Ideapad L340-15IRH, i5-9300H, Gpu(s) Gtx 1650, Intel HD 630.

Please help me, what am I doing wrong?

Code to enable transparency, using `windows.h` inside a C++ function:

```
HWND hWnd = GetActiveWindow();
res = SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, RGB(255, 255, 255), 0, LWA_COLORKEY);
```

Code which creates the transparent background, in main haxe code:

```
transparentsquare = new FlxSprite(0, 0).makeGraphic(screenW, screenH, FlxColor.WHITE);
add(transparentsquare);
```

It doesn't matter if I enable transparency before everything has loaded, I can enable it by pressing a key at any time and it still fails if I enable it after the app has fully loaded. Also, obviously graphics are not drawn in the C++ function but in the haxe code, so I can't use any fancy DirectX APIs and what-not.

Comment: Why are you using GetActiveWindow() to get the HWND? If you don't own the window, you have no business manipulating its transparency outside of its control.

Comment: I'm using GetActiveWindow since that's the only way to get the HWND outside of the main haxe code, the HWND isn't the problem since I can manipulate the entire window to be transparent, but just the colour keying doesn't work on the main monitor

Comment: So `LWA_ALPHA` works but `LWA_COLORKEY` works only on a different monitor